# A JSON web token could not be decoded

Tags: ruby, python-3.x, jwt, github-api, pyjwt

I'm attempting to port the GitHub Apps sample starter code from Ruby to Python, but I'm running into trouble whilst generating the required JWT. The [Ruby script](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps/#authenticating-as-a-github-app) looks like this, and works fine:

```rb
require 'openssl'
require 'jwt'  # https://rubygems.org/gems/jwt

private_pem = File.read(YOUR_PATH_TO_PEM)
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(private_pem)

payload = {
  iat: Time.now.to_i,
  exp: Time.now.to_i + (10 * 60),
  iss: GITHUB_APP_IDENTIFIER
}

jwt = JWT.encode(payload, private_key, "RS256")
puts jwt
```

My Python script is as follows and produces the `A JSON web token could not be decoded` error when used against the GitHub API:

```py
import os
import time
import jwt

APP_IDENTIFIER = os.environ["GITHUB_APP_IDENTIFIER"]

with open('./PRIVATE_KEY.pem', 'r') as f:
    PRIVATE_KEY = f.read()

payload = {"iat": int(time.time()),
           "exp": int(time.time()) + (10*60),
           "iss": APP_IDENTIFIER}

print(jwt.encode(payload, PRIVATE_KEY, algorithm='RS256'))
```

When I tried printing the private keys from both scripts, I found that the Ruby version had an extra newline character. I tried adding this to the private key in the Python script, but it didn't change the output.

My best guess is that the difference is something to do with the `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new` call, but I'm not sure what that does to the key.

Comment: You might find the online debugger at jwt.io helpful to compare the two generated tokens.  Do the claims match (up to the timestamps)?  Can it validate the signatures against your public key?

Answer (score 4):

`jwt.encode()` will return you bytes in Python 3 which probably ends up having `str()` called on it somewhere in the sending pipeline. Calling `str()` on bytes objects in Python 3 can result in potentially surprising behaviour:

```
>>> a = b'hello'
>>> str(a)
"b'hello'"
```

The correct way to turn bytes into a string in Python 3 is to use:

```
>>> a.decode('utf-8')
'hello'
```

I added the call to `decode` on the end of my `jwt.encode` line and the API suddenly had no problems decoding the JWT.